# CA65 NES issue with INY STY

Tags: assembly, 6502, ca65, nes

I am new to CA65 and am trying to transfer a NESASM project over to it.  I translated everything and it builds.  When I run I get nothing.  Just a black screen.  Diving deeper I have an infinite loop.  It seems to be having an issue with increasing the Y (INY) and then whatever I set after it doesn't take.
[image]

You can see that after INY at 8505 Y becomes 1.  Setting the variable I have at $84A8 to Y should change it to $01 but it doesn't.  Because of this, I enter an infinite loop.  Am I doing something wrong here? It has been a bit since I have programmed assembly but this seems pretty easy.

Let me know if I am doing something wrong or you need more information.

Comment: _"the variable I have at $84A8"_. Which mapper are you using? IIRC all commonly used mappers have ROM (and possibly mapper control registers) at $8xxx.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I should be using Mapper 0 for now, that's what I was using in NESASM.  And that is a good point.  I guess the thing I don't understand is how we control where in memory our variables get assigned with CA65.  I know that I have some pointer variables in the "ZEROPAGE" segment because that is where they need to be.  But the rest of my variables are in the "CODE" segment which is where I thought they needed to be.  I thought the linker handled memory placement outside of that.  I suppose I need to do more research on CA65.

Comment: The CODE segment will be in ROM. For variables you should probably use the DATA or BSS segment.

Comment: If you're using Mapper 0, you've got the ```$0000-$07FF``` range as your RAM, and that's all you get. Everything else is either ROM or hardware registers.

Comment: Now some mappers actually do require you to write to ROM to do certain things (such as the VRC6 and its additional sound hardware) but Mapper 0 is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your variables are in writable memory.

The NES normally has 2KB of RAM, so you're better off using addresses below $0800.

Because you're writing to $84a8, you're not actually saving the register to any memory because that address is mapped to ROM. So that location will not actually change.